# how minify and obfuscate multiple js files with multiple output file with dependencies

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I would like to minify and obfuscate multiple js files (for example first.js, second.js and so on..) and get multiple minified files (so first.min.js, second.min.js etc.) but I have the problem that every js files have some dependencies among them (for example: second.js calls a function of first.js). 
Then the compiler process (like Closure Compiler) should analyse them all together. Unfortunately Closure Compiler Online provides as result a single js file, instead the jar version of Closure Compiler requires to specify which files depends by others (and I don't know it...). 
Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You should ask this at Software Recommendations. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you try jscrambler (https://jscrambler.com/en/). I've used some solutions for minification/obfuscation and that one  seems to solve your problem because it supports multiple files/full projects.
As far as I've used it works as expected but check for yourself. Hope it helps.